# Advices for the construction of a Telegram bot

Tags: api, mobile, push-notification, raspberry-pi, telegram-bot

This question is about finding some ideas in order to implement a sort of publisher-subscriber service via a Telegram bot. Have a look here:

[image]

Let's say I have an API in a self hosted Raspberry PI, and I want to add a modern interface in order to present that API produced data via a Telegram Bot. In this way, people can subscribe to my bot and receiving real-time updates (for instance if the API is about weather, clients can know updated weather forecast).

I have some experience with Python programming, so let me know if it is possible to implement this kind of service with the tools I have at my disposal.

Thank you.